# Can't find automoc4 on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, kde4, cmake

I was trying to build dekorator, but

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:198 (MESSAGE):
  Did not find automoc4 (Automoc4Config.cmake, install
  git://anongit.kde.org/automoc).  (missing: AUTOMOC4_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindAutomoc4.cmake:49 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:423 (find_package)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:95 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

But automoc4 was installed already.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/31105).

The workaround is to add a line to the `cmake` command in your PKGBUILD:

```
-DAutomoc4_DIR=/usr/lib/automoc4
```

There is also a [forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145612) with a more general solution; adding a line to your shell file:

```
export Automoc4_DIR=/usr/lib/automoc4
```